# Fail2ban (0.9.6-2) with pure-ftpd (1.0.46)

Tags: linux, fail2ban, pure-ftpd

I'm using pureftpd and fail2ban but is not working. It seems is able to read the log but the `fail2ban.filter` event is not triggered. I investigated a lot about all the possible problems and I already did a lot of checks but I don't know why this is not working. I'll start putting my configs, logs and what I did. Before, I must say I already have on the same maching running ok fail2ban against apache and ssh. The problem is only happening with pureftpd.:

on my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[pureftpd]
enabled = true
port = 21
filter = pure-ftpd
logpath = /var/log/messages
backend = polling
maxretry = 5
```

I changed this thousands of times (restarting fail2ban daemon after each change of course). Tested `port = ftp` instead of `port = 21` seems to have the same result. I tried using `backend = auto` or removing backend statement... same result.

My `/var/log/messages` is receiving ok the attemps of login into the ftp, some lines as example:

```
Aug  3 08:31:01 88a4998e8b37 pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.0.159) [INFO] New connection from 192.168.0.159
Aug  3 08:31:09 88a4998e8b37 pure-ftpd: (?@192.168.0.159) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [testinguser]
```

My `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/pure-ftpd.conf`:

```
[Definition]
__errmsg = Authentication failed for user
failregex = pure-ftpd: \(\?@<HOST>\) \[WARNING\] %(__errmsg)s \[.+\]$
ignoreregex =
```

I tested this doing `fail2ban-regex /var/log/messages /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/pure-ftpd.conf` and it returns a lot of hits, so I think is working.

I also put fail2ban into debug mode, and this is the log while a user connect and tries to login failing:

```
2017-08-03 03:31:10,163 fail2ban.filterpoll     [4429]: DEBUG   /var/log/messages has been modified
2017-08-03 03:31:10,164 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Matched time template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2017-08-03 03:31:10,165 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Got time 1470231069.000000 for "'Aug  3 08:31:09'" using template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2017-08-03 03:31:10,165 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Sorting the template list
2017-08-03 03:31:10,166 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Winning template: (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)? with 2 hits
```

So it is detecting the file is changing but the filter is not triggered. Why?

Comparing with my other fail2ban services working (apache for example), I saw in the logs a difference... when it works a lines likes these appears in the logs:

```
2017-08-03 03:43:37,024 fail2ban.filterpoll     [4429]: DEBUG   /var/log/apache2/error.log has been modified
2017-08-03 03:43:37,025 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Matched time template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2017-08-03 03:43:37,026 fail2ban.datedetector   [4429]: DEBUG   Got time 1501767816.000000 for "'Thu Aug 03 08:43:36.224686 2017'" using template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2017-08-03 03:43:37,026 fail2ban.filter         [4429]: DEBUG   Processing line with time:1501767816.0 and ip:192.168.0.154
2017-08-03 03:43:37,027 fail2ban.filter         [4429]: INFO    [apache] Found 192.168.0.154
```

So, everything seems similar checking the files... it gets the time but nothing triggered after that. What can be happening? Somebody experienced this before? Thank you.

Comment: Is pureFTP definitely listing on port 21? Have you done a `netstat -an` to confirm it?

Comment: Even if you put the right user/pass from other machine you can connect and download files from ftp. To be honest is a little bit more complicated... but I tried to reduce the info to avoid a very long post. The pureftpd is a docker container and it has mapped ports 21 and some others for passive connections. The log is mapped to from the container to the host and fail2ban is able to read it. I have the same scenario on apache (containerized too) and is working. To be honest, I think that is not the point that's because I ommited it.

Comment: I know there are problems with the iptables rules for this kind of scenario because docker have a lot of iptables rules and once ban is launched, the machine can be still hit because it hits a FORWARD rule before fail2ban rule... I know how to fix that (I already have it for apache working)... but that's another story... at least it should appear in the log as trying to ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved now. The problem was the timezone was different inside the container from that was set on the host. Read this "wrong issue" I put on fail2ban's github:

https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1855#event-1195174858